# Reducing UTC Date Using PHP + jQuery Datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui-datepicker, utc

I have a jQuery datepicker for a user to select a `dueBy` date (mm/dd/yyyy) that gets stored in a MySQL database. The user can successfully select a date in the datepicker and submit/save the record. I use the following method to convert the m/d/Y to a UTC format:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y", $_POST['dueBy']);
$values['dueBy'] = $date->format('U');
```

Then when the user views the record again, I convert the UTC time back to an easily readable format:

```
$dueBy = date('m/d/Y', $aQ->dueBy);
```

I fill the datepicker with the formatted dueBy date where the user can either leave it as is, or can select a new date.

The issue is this: upon updating the record, the date shifts back one (1) day each save. E.g. if it's originally 03/03/2015, it will save to 03/02/2015. If I open and save the record again, it saves as 03/01/2015.

This is the code using to save (exactly the same as when we create the record):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y", $_POST['dueBy']);
$values['dueBy'] = $date->format('U');
```

I've viewed the record each time to view the values, and they aren't decreasing consistently (e.g. one value has reduced by 86390, and then a few minutes later it had reduced by 86368).

Can anyone explain why this is happening, and how to avoid it?

Comment: In this command, `$dueBy = date('m/d/Y', $aQ->dueBy);` I am skeptical that `$aQ->dueBy` outputs a PHP Time().  The `date(format,time)` function expects the second parameter to be an integer value for seconds since Jan 1,1970. Can you check and let us know what the var_dump() output is for the `$aQ->dueBy` variable? If it is not seconds, I would do this: `$dueBy = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($aQ->dueBy));`.

Comment: @FactoryAidan Sure thing - var_dump returns this: `string(10) "1425403080"`

Comment: @FactoryAidan If I change it to an INT would that solve my problem?

Comment: It's worth a try but I think the date() function takes care of doing that for you. Casting as int would/should be as easy as  `(int)$aQ->dueBy`.  Try it and let us know... I'll keep thinking on it.

Comment: @FactoryAidan Okay so I switched it in the database (it's local on my machine, easy fix) - that didn't seem to help. And now it's setting the date back on the initial new record save (originally it would save correctly and only decrease each time the record was added).

Comment: The way I check these things is doing a var_dump() after each command to see where a change occurs.  I would do that above and below each line where the date gets touched.  But I want to mention the long-shot of doing a  `var_dump()` on your `$_POST['dueBy']` variable to make sure the forward-slashes aren't getting escaped with back-slashes when the request gets packaged by the browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72107/discussion-between-factoryaidan-and-lauren).